# How to parse different types of objects / arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

What is the different between these two parsing's that I'm getting from two separate PHP cURL's:

**Part 1:**

```
{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : {
        "cat" : "dog"
    }
```

}

I tried:

```
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
echo $obj->result->cat;
```

To try and return "dog".

**Part 2:**

```
(
    [item] => T-Shirt
    [orderId] => 7652393
    [clientOrderId] => 12345
    [transactTime] => 1508564815865
    [price] => 1.50
)
```

I tried:

```
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
echo $obj['price'];
```

To try and return "1.50".

Am I doing these right?

Comment: What results do you get? To see what the decoded json look like you could: var_dump($obj);

Comment: The input that you're parsing in Part 2 is not JSON. It looks like the output of the `print_r()` function, which isn't meant to be machine-parseable.

Answer (score 0):

**PART 1**

```
<?php 

$json = '{
"success" : true,
"message" : "",
"result" : {
        "cat" : "dog"
    }

}';

$parsedJson = json_decode($json, true); // json to array conversion 

echo $parsedJson["result"]["cat"];


?>
```

**Part 2**

```
(
    [item] => T-Shirt
    [orderId] => 7652393
    [clientOrderId] => 12345
    [transactTime] => 1508564815865
    [price] => 1.50
)
```

> Above string is not json i think this is array so you can use

```
echo $array["price"]; // suppose your array var name is $array
```